# The sides $a>b>c$ of a triangle are integers such that $3^a, 3^b, 3^c$ leave the same remainder when divided by $10000$.

Tags: geometry, number-theory

The sides $a>b>c$ of a triangle are integers such that $3^a, 3^b, 3^c$ leave the same remainder when divided by $10000$. Find the minimum value of the perimeter of such a triangle.

---

Since $3^a, 3^b,3^c$ leave the same remainder $$3^a \equiv 3^b\equiv 3^c\pmod{10000}$$

I feel stuck after this... Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10000\mid 3^b-3^c=3^c(3^{b-c}-1)$ So $10000\mid 3^{b-c}-1$.

And similarly $10000\mid 3^{a-b}-1$.

So you need those two conditions and $b+c>a$.

Comment: Thank you so much! $$10000|3^x-1 \implies 3^x\equiv 1\pmod{10000}$$ should I be searching $x$ from the divisors of $\phi(10000) = \phi(2^45^4) = (2^4-2^3)(5^4-5^3) = 4000$ ? or is there any easy way to find the $least$ exponent that yields $1$ in mod $10000$ ? xD

Comment: @rsadhvika See my answer below for the computation of this number, which is just the exponent of $\mathbb{Z}_{10000}^{\times}$; for the formulas justifying the isomorphisms, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_odd_primes .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $r, n$ are coprime, then the sequence of remainders of powers $r^m$ modulo some number $n$ is a sequence of powers of an element $[r]$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$. Since $10000 = 2^4 5^4$, the Chinese Remainder Theorem gives that the ring $\mathbb{Z} / 10000 \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z} / 2^4 \mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z} / 5^4 \mathbb{Z})$, and so $$(\mathbb{Z} / 10000 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong (\mathbb{Z} / 2^4 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 5^4 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z} / (2^3 \cdot 1) \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / (5^3 \cdot 4) = \mathbb{Z} / 8 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 500 \mathbb{Z}.$$ So, every element of $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}_{10000}^{\times}$ has order dividing $500$ (this is the [Carmichael Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) for $n = 10000$). On the other hand, $3^k \not\equiv 
1 \bmod 10000$ for $k = 100, 250$, so $3$ has order $500$. Thus, $3^a \equiv 3^b \equiv 3^c \bmod 10000$ iff $a \equiv b \equiv c \bmod 500$, that is, iff $a = c + 500 k, b = c + 500 l$, for some integers $k, l$ such that $k > l > 0$.

Now, the positive numbers $a, b, c$, $a \geq b \geq c$, form the sides of a triangle iff $a < b + c$, or in our case, $500 (k - l) < c$.